# Understanding proposition related to algebras of subsets of the reals

Tags: measure-theory

A proposition in a lecture script on measure and integration theory reads:

> **Proposition 1.1.4** Let $$\mathcal{I} = \{ (a,b]: -\infty \leq a < b < \infty \}\cup\{ (b,\infty) : -\infty < b < \infty \}\cup\{ \emptyset \}\cup\mathbb{R}.$$ Then $$ 
> \epsilon = \left\{ \bigcup_{i=1}^N I_i : N \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } I_i \in \mathcal{I} \text{ for } i = 1, 2, \dots, N \right\}
> $$ is an algebra of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

I don't really understand the point here. It would seem that all the elements of the union defining $\mathcal{I}$ are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, and they exhaust the reals because one element of the union is $\mathbb{R}$, so $\mathcal{I} = \mathbb{R}$. Where is my thinking going wrong? Also, I don't understand the big union defining $\epsilon$. No expression in the equation defining $\mathcal{I}$ is indexed by $i$, so $I_i = I_j ~{\forall} i, j \in \mathbb{N}$. Could the index belong to $a$ and $b$ and just be missing?

I appreciate any help in resolving my confusion.

**EDIT**: I understand that the last element of the union defining $\mathcal{I}$ should be $\{\mathbb{R}\}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$, so that it should read $$\mathcal{I} = \{ (a,b]: -\infty \leq a < b < \infty \}\cup\{ (b,\infty) : -\infty < b < \infty \}\cup\{ \emptyset \}\cup\{\mathbb{R}\}.$$

but as I am quoting original material I don't think it should be corrected in the quote.

Comment: This is indeed strange looking. Do you have more context you can provide? An image or link to where this appears, perhaps?

Comment: In the definition of $\mathcal I$, the $\mathbb R$ at the end should be $\{\mathbb R\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misinterpreting what $\mathcal{I}$ is. $\mathcal{I}$ is a collection (set) of subsets (more specifically, certain types of intervals) of $\mathbb{R}$. In other words, $\mathcal{I}$ is a subset of $\operatorname{Pow}(\mathbb{R})$, but **NOT** a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. That's why $\mathcal{I}$ can't possibly be equal to $\mathbb{R}$.

For example, to make it simple, let's consider just the last two parts of this definition of $\mathcal{I}$. Let $\mathcal{J}=\{\varnothing\}\cup\{\mathbb{R}\}$. Then $\mathcal{J}$ is just a two element set $\mathcal{J}=\{\varnothing,\mathbb{R}\}$, which is **VERY DIFFERENT** from $\varnothing\cup\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}$.

The union that defines $\mathcal{I}$ describes the fact that the **elements** of $\mathcal{I}$ are the empty set $\varnothing$, the entire set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ (as a single element!), and two types of intervals of the form $(a,b]$ and $(b,+\infty)$, respectively. For example, this definition says that the following are **elements** of $\mathcal{I}$:
$$(2,15]\in\mathcal{I}, \quad (\pi,+\infty)\in\mathcal{I}, \quad \varnothing\in\mathcal{I}, \quad \text{and} \quad \mathbb{R}\in\mathcal{I}.$$
But they are **NOT** subsets of $\mathcal{I}$ (except for the empty set, which is always a subset of anything):
$$(2,15]\not\subseteq\mathcal{I}, \quad (\pi,+\infty)\not\subseteq\mathcal{I}, \quad \text{and} \quad \mathbb{R}\not\subseteq\mathcal{I}.$$

**UPDATE.**  Here's what the definition of $\epsilon$ says. Imagine that $\mathcal{I}$ is a bin containing a lot of elements in it — each one being an interval in $\mathbb{R}$ (of certain types), including the empty one and the whole real number line. To create any one element of $\epsilon$, we reach into that bin and pick out any finite number of any elements from it. And then, just for convenience of referencing, we're going to label them — we'll say that $N$ is the number of the elements we picked out, and we'll label them (randomly) as $I_1$ (element $\#1$), $I_2$ (element $\#2$), …, $I_N$ (element $\#N$). In fact, all we want to do is set up the union of the elements that we picked out; but in order to say that with a formula without words, we label them as above, and now we can say that we've constructed a specific element of $\epsilon$ as $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^N I_i$. Then we can reach into the bin again, pick another bunch of elements, and set up their union — referencing that new bunch will have its own $N$ and its own labels $I_1$, $I_2$, etc.

The four elements that I used above can be an example of one instance of this procedure, although it's not a very interesting one. In this case, $N=4$, and we can label $I_1=(2,15]$, $I_2=(\pi,+\infty)$, $I_3=\varnothing$, and $I_4=\mathbb{R}$. Then the element of $\epsilon$ constructed using this selection will be
$$\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^4 I_i=(2,15]\cup(\pi,+\infty)\cup\varnothing\cup\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}\in\epsilon.$$
You can see a better example of an element of $\epsilon$ in the other answer by @Cameron Buie.

Comment: That clarifies it a lot. Do I understand correctly then that in this example, $N = 4$ and the elements of $\mathcal{I}$ are implicitly indexed by $i$?

Comment: @Constantin: No, not exactly. I was explain what $\mathcal{I}$ is, but I didn't talk about the algebra of sets $\epsilon$. I'm going to make an update to my answer now.

Comment: Could $\mathcal{I} = \{ (a,b]: -\infty \leq a < b < \infty \}\cup\{ (b,\infty) : -\infty < b < \infty \}, \{ \emptyset \}\cup\{\mathbb{R}\}$ be rewritten as $\mathcal{I} = \{\{ (a,b]: -\infty \leq a < b < \infty \}, \{ (b,\infty) : -\infty < b < \infty \}, \{ \emptyset \}, \{\mathbb{R}\}\}$?

Comment: @Constantin: No. What you wrote is a set consisting of **FOUR** elements only (each one of them being a set of sets in its own right). This is **NOT** the same as the original $\mathcal{I}$, which has infinitely many elements.

Comment: If the last argument of the union defining $\mathcal{I}$ is $\mathbb{R}$, then $\mathcal{I}$ is the set such that all of its elements are elements of $\mathbb{R}$, since all other arguments in the union are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. This, while apparently incorrect, is how it's written in the script. If the last element in the union $\mathcal{I}$ is $\{\mathbb{R}\}$, then the four arguments of the union are elements (not subsets) of $\mathcal{I}$. Does using commata in defining $\mathcal{I}$ somehow imply that the expression is true only for some values of $a$ and $b$ instead of for any values?

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is that if a set is constructed as the union of four sets each containing only one set, why doesn't it have four elements? If it were constructed as the union of sets directly containing reals (removing the outermost pairs of parentheses), I understand that the union would be an infinite set. But with each argument of the union containing only one set, the union itself will consist of the sets that are its arguments (not their elements), of which in this case there are four, no? (No matter how many sets they themselves contain.)

Comment: @Constantin: Quick example to illustrate the difference. $\{1,2,3\}\cup\{4,5\}=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ is a set consisting of **FIVE** elements: $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, and $5$. But $\{\{1,2,3\},\{4,5\}\}$ doesn't simplify, and it's a set consisting of **TWO** elements: $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{4,5\}$.

Comment: @Constantin: In the original union, the first two sets are not `"each containing only one set"`. In fact, each of them contains infinitely many elements, but those elements are **NOT** real numbers -- they are intervals. In the union $\mathcal{I}=\{ (a,b]:-\infty\leq a<b< \infty\}\cup\ldots$, this first part consists of things like $\{ (a,b]:-\infty\leq a<b< \infty\}=\{(1,2],(\pi,e^2],(-11.38,765.567],\ldots\}$. Even if we take its union with $\mathbb{R}$ (as erroneously written in the source), it won't be $\mathbb{R}$ because this set and $\mathbb{R}$ have no elements in common.

Comment: Okay, got it. That clarifies it a lot. Thank you! About the erroneous $\mathbb{R}$; could you briefly explain why this must be erroneous? It's consistently written without braces throughout the script. Then I'll be happy to accept your answer.

Comment: @Constantin: The reason we know that it should be $\{\Bbb R\},$ rather than $\Bbb R,$ is that we're talking about an algebra of subsets of the reals. The elements of the reals are *not* subsets of the reals--in general, they aren't even thought of as *sets*, so the elements of $\mathcal I$ would be ill-defined in that case, as union is an operation of sets. However, even if we have constructed $\Bbb R$ in some set theoretic model, we would still run into the problem that, in general, the elements of $\Bbb R$ aren't subsets of $\Bbb R,$ so $\epsilon$ would fail to be an algebra of such subsets.

Comment: @Constantin: Now, it *may be* possible to construct $\Bbb R$ in such a way that each element of $\Bbb R$ is a subset of $\Bbb R,$ but this is *far* from common practice, so unless you've been shown a particular construction of $\Bbb R$ such that this is true, I would suspect that it is an (apparently persistent) error.

Answer (score 2):

What it means is that the elements of $\epsilon$ are precisely the finite unions of elements of $\mathcal I.$ For example, $(0,1]\cup(2,\infty)$ would be an element of $\epsilon.$

Put another way, given an arbitrary natural number $N,$ and arbitrary sets $I_1,...,I_N\in\mathcal I,$ we have that $\bigcup_{i=1}^NI_i$ is an element of $\epsilon.$ Moreover, all elements of $\epsilon$ are constructed in such a way.

Comment: Welcome back, Cameron!